# PreloadJS is undefined(Windows 8 game programming)

Tags: javascript, debugging, windows-8, microsoft-metro, createjs

I am new to metro style programming so I am following a tutorial here http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-game-basics-createjseaseljs/ for games using createJS. Here the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>game</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- game references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="/js/CreateJS/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/CreateJS/preloadjs-0.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's javascript code

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
WinJS.strictProcessing();


function initialize() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    preload = new PreloadJS();
    preload.onComplete = prepareGame;
    var manifest = [
        { id: "screenImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/gameplay_screen.png" },
        { id: "redImage", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redIdle/redIdle.png" },
        { id: "blueImage", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueIdle/blueIdle.png" },
        { id: "ammoImage", src: "images/Ammo/rock_ammo.png" },
        { id: "winImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/victory.png" },
        { id: "loseImage", src: "images/Backgrounds/defeat.png" },
        { id: "blueFire", src: "images/Catapults/Blue/blueFire/blueCatapult_fire.png" },
        { id: "redFire", src: "images/Catapults/Red/redFire/redCatapult_fire.png" },
    ];

    preload.loadManifest(manifest);


    stage = new Stage(canvas);
}

function prepareGame() {
    bgImage = preload.getResult("screenImage").result;
    bgBitmap = new Bitmap(bgImage);
    bgBitmap.scaleX = SCALE_X;
    bgBitmap.scaleY = SCALE_Y;
    stage.addChild(bgBitmap);

    stage.update();
}

function gameLoop() {

}

function update() {

}

function draw() {

}

var canvas, context, stage;
var bgImage, p1Image, p2Image, ammoImage, p1lives, p2lives, title, endGameImage;
var bgBitmap, p1Bitmap, p2Bitmap, ammoBitmap;
var preload;

// Current Display Factor. Because the orignal assumed a 800x480 screen
var SCALE_X = window.innerWidth / 800;
var SCALE_Y = window.innerHeight / 480;
var MARGIN = 25;
var GROUND_Y = 390 * SCALE_Y;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);

app.start();
})();
```

Now the problem is that whenever I try to compile the code it gives me the Preload is undefined error. I do not understand the reason I have included the script in HTML and file in my project. Would somebody please help this problem has been killing me for the last hour and I just want to make a simple game.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  This catapult war source code from the sitepoint website does not to seem to work in the final Windows 8 and Visual Studio Express 2012 version.  Maybe it worked in the Windows 8 RC.  There appears to be something incompatible with the PreloadJS and/or EaselJS as it is never able to load any images onto the canvas.  The Sitepoint website on this game was last updated Aug. 2012.

Comment: @user785179 ya i did got it working after hours of struggle. The author forgot to mention to add package name i.e `createjs.` before calling the class

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I did find a github page of someone who posted his complete Catapult Wars working code. https://github.com/dave-pointbypoint/CatapultGame.  Hopefully this helps others looking for a working solution in other parts of their programming adventures when they stumble upon this useful page.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that the libraries have been placed under the "createjs" namespace. In order to instantiate the PreloadJS object, please do the following:

```
var preload = new createjs.PreloadJS();
```

That should get you back to happy path.

Answer (score 2):

(Tried on Feb 2013, after PreloadJS 0.3.0 released)

I just tried the tutorial from sitepoint.com (http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-simple-windows-8-game-with-javascript-game-basics-createjseaseljs/), using the latest versions of EaselJS and PreloadJS, but I couldn't get the code to run without errors at first.

The new version of PreloadJS (v0.3.0) has renamed the old PreloadJS class to LoadQueue.

See the documentation at the links below:

- http://www.createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/classes/PreloadJS.html
- http://www.createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/classes/LoadQueue.html

But simply using the new class while using v0.3.0 doesn't fix the project. The newer version has additional incompatibilities (e.g. image.width is not valid) which can probably be fixed by trial and error.

I had to download the older PreloadJS v0.2.0:

- https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/tags

**IN A NUTSHELL:** If I use the SitePoint tutorial, I have to stick with PreloadJS v0.2.0 and also use the createjs namespace.

*NOTE*: The sample project mentioned in a previous response doesn't work either, because its WinJS references are invalid. Adding the reference manually doesn't seem to work either.

- https://github.com/dave-pointbypoint/CatapultGame

Comment: There are definitely some changes, but not too many.  Mostly you have to prepend a lot of things with a namespace, like Bitmap becomes createjs.Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Move your default.js in the HTML to be *after* the preloadjs & easel code.

This is because the order of inclusion is important to JavaScript

Comment: well after few hours of struggle i finally was able to catch the bug. It seems that either author of the tutorial did some referencing beforehand and forgot to mention it in the tutorial or there was something changed in the libraries since the tutorial. Anyways just add `createjs.` package name before calling the class.